# Entity property calculated from DB data

Tags: symfony, architecture, entity

This question maybe is more related to architecture and application design more than development itself. Here it goes:

I have an entity defined with date and session (AM or PM), and I need a get/set property to know if *isReservedAllDay()*, which mean, this entity has a complimentary entity reserved in same day but different session.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class HallReservation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string: "AM" | "PM"
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="session", type="string")
     */
    private $session;
```

This *isReservedAllDay()* or *getReservedAllDay()* is actually set by accessing database, which of course, should be out of scope of an entity and done in controller or service.

My first solution is to do so, a query in controller to *set* de property and then be able to *get* this property value on twig, forms or wherever, without ever persisting or even mapping this property, this may be a proper solution from the architecture point of view (or maybe not!) but not nice from the point of view of develoment, as it forces me to set the property everytime I get an instance.

```
function setReservedAllDay($reserved)
{
    $this->reservedAllDay = $reserved;
    return $this;
}

function getReservedAllDay()
{
    return $this->reservedAllDay;
}
```

Could you criticize this approach or suggest a better one?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to persist this as a boolean in the database? This just seems like a bool value to me.

Comment: The reason is: this is a calculated field, I prefer to "calculate" everytime I need to use it better than persisting it and everytime I delete a reservation having to query and modify this field (this method is less prone to errors)

Comment: Just doing the thing you want to in a more automatic way: Use a postLoad doctrine listener (inject the event dispatcher into this), then if a `HallReservation` is loaded dispatch a custom event (which holds the entity as payload) through the dispatcher, with another listener for that custom event do your logic and set the value. This way you won't need to call it manually in the controller. The custom event is needed because you can't inject the entity manager into the doctrine event listener (cyclic dependency issue). That should be one way to go

Comment: @Joe I'll need some time to digest this but I think that is what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: It's actually quite simple i'll provide an example in a moment maybe that clarifies it a bit more

Comment: Do the `getReservedAllDay` method retrieve an array collection of `HallReservation` ? What is problem that doctrine perform a database query to load sub entities ? Maybe I'm missunderstanding

Comment: @Joe: *The custom event is needed because you can't inject the entity manager into the doctrine event listener (cyclic dependency issue).* - The doctrine callbacks receive an instance of LifecycleEventArgs, which already gives access to the entity manager through `getEntityManager` (see [Link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.Event.LifecycleEventArgs.html))

Comment: @ccKep of course you are right. that makes it even easier. needed to go through a custom event in my own use case because of another service that needed the entityManager and therefore couldn't be injected directly. Forgot about direct access to entityManger only through the event :oops:

Comment: @K.Weber There are several possible solutions: You could also create a custom twig extension with a function (something like `isReservedAllDay(reservation)` which does the calculation on the entity it gets passed, a twig macro could be used aswell. Putting such methods into a service might be a good idea aswell (something like `ReservationService` - you could also gather other useful methods in there).

Comment: @Mcsky that method returns a boolean value. The problem is not with Doctrine, it's more on "where" to implement the database access as an entity is not a place for that. Joe's solution seems the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the value through a doctrine listener for example.
Just copied/typed this together so it'll probably not be fully working but you should get the idea.
Maybe this approach will cover your needs.

**Edit: Like ccKep mentioned the entityManager is already available through the `LifecycleEventArgs` in the `postLoad` function directly. Adding the custom event would only be needed if you need another service that depends on the entityManager and can't be injected directly because of that.**
I'll leave the code here unchanged maybe it could be useful to someone else (who needs more than the entityManager).

The doctrine listener:

```
class HallReservationLoadListener
{
    /** @var  EventDispatcherInterface */
    protected $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $item = $args->getEntity();
        if($item instanceof HallReservation) {
            $event = new HallReservationLoadedEvent($item);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(HallReservationLoadedEvent::NAME, $event);
        }

    }
}
```

The custom event:

```
class HallReservationLoadedEvent extends Event
{
    const NAME = 'hallreservation.loaded';

    protected $hallreservation;

    public function __construct(HallReservation $hallreservation)
    {
        $this->hallreservation = $hallreservation;
    }

    public function getHallreservation()
    {
        return $this->hallreservation;
    }
}
```

The listener for your custom event:

```
class HallReservationReservedListener
{
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function setReservedProperty(HallReservationLoadedEvent $event)
    {
        $hallreservation = $event->getHallreservation();
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Services definitions:

```
app.listener.hallreservationload:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\HallReservationLoadListener
        arguments: ['@event_dispatcher']
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
    app.listener.hallreservationload.reservedproperty:
        class: AppBundle\Listener\HallReservationReservedListener
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: 'hallreservation.loaded', method: 'setReservedProperty'}
```